# Changing settings of the 3D view with Python

Tags: scripting, python

I am a beginner with python, and prompted by my [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/render-with-opengl-from-the-command-line), I was trying to set viewport shading to *Solid* and *View Only Render* to *True* with python. (The goal being to get the script in that answer to work entirely from python without any need for interaction with the GUI)

however, simply typing [`show_only_render`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68a_release/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.show_only_render)`= True` or [`viewport_shade`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68a_release/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.viewport_shade)`= 'SOLID'` in the console results in nothing happening.

From what I can understand from a lot of searching, is that the cursor needs to be in the 3D view for that object to be active.

It is suggested [here](http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=89711&sid=c18d5fe9e5dcc5bb622fa9ad20d53692) to loop through all the *areas* to do this.

I tried doing this and setting the *view* to *camera*, *shading* to *solid*, and *view only render* to *true.*

However, what actually happens is that the view is set to camera, and the image is rendered without changing *view only render* to *True*.

Modified version of the [script originally written by Adhi in my previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/render-with-opengl-from-the-command-line/2575#2575), with changes suggested by Aldrik in the answer below:

```
import bpy
import sys                      # read argument from sys.argv
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def do_render_opengl(dummy):
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
      if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
      #if area.type == 'SpaceView3D' :
      area.spaces[0].show_only_render = True
      area.spaces[0].viewport_shade = 'SOLID'
    bpy.data.scenes[0].render.filepath="/tmp/glrender.png"
    bpy.ops.render.opengl(animation=False, write_still=True, view_context=True)
    bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(do_render_opengl)
```

---

***Update:***
*I have changed the script with Aldrik's improvements, but when I run it with*
`blender -P gl_render.py example.blend`, *It returns:*

```
File "/home/gandalf3/Blender/Opengl_render.py", line 11, in do_render_opengl
    area.spaces[0].show_only_render = True
AttributeError: 'SpaceInfo' object has no attribute 'show_only_render'
```

It seems that it's still not in the right context?

Comment: There's an example of changing viewport shading in: [Is it possible to change viewport draw mode when navigating?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1913/290).

Comment: @gandalf3: The two lines below commented conditional must be indented (within first `if area.type`'s block). Their current state made them executed for *every* area type, not what you intended.

Comment: @Adhi ah, thanks. I didn't realize that `VIEW_3D` is `SpaceView3D`.. it works now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`show_only_render`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.show_only_render) and [`viewport_shade`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.viewport_shade) are *attributes* of the [`SpaceView3D`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html). So for your usage example you'd make the following change:

```
-      if area.type == 'SpaceView3D' :
-        show_only_render = True
-        viewport_shade = 'SOLID'
+        area.spaces[0].show_only_render = True
+        area.spaces[0].viewport_shade = 'SOLID'
```

Comment: I'd use [`spaces.active`](http://localhost/blender_python_reference_2_67_release/bpy.types.AreaSpaces.html#bpy.types.AreaSpaces.active) just to make sure, but it'd be good too if first item in any collection is always the active one.

Comment: @Adhi [Docs say it is so](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.spaces). ;)

Comment: @Aldrik though this may be the implementation it's still (IMO) semantically better to use `spaces.active` because that's what you logically care about - the internal representation isn't really important. It also makes it more clear what you're doing (e.g., any reader of the code would be momentarily distracted exactly as was Adhi) and thus more maintainable.